# Write method that puts the word "like" in between each of the words in the original sentence

Tags: java

I need to write a method that puts the word "like" in between each of the words in the original sentence.

For example:

`teenTalk("That is so funny!")` 
would return "That like is like so like funny!"

Would you use sentence split for this?

Comment: any try by using a replace method:????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the space character with "like":

`text.replace(" ", " like ");`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
String teenTalk(String source) {
    return String.join(" like ", source.split(" "));
}
```

or like this:

```
String teenTalk(String source) {
    return source.replaceAll(" ", " like ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String testJoiner = "That is so funny!";
  // Split the string into list of word
  List<String> splited = Arrays.asList(testJoiner.split("\\s"));
  // create new StringJoiner that add the delimiter like between each entry
  StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" like ");
  // internal iteration over the words and adding them into the joiner
  splited.forEach(joiner::add);
  // printing the new value
  System.out.println(joiner.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very efficient but the first thing that comes to mind is something "like" this:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

 public String teenTalk(String inputString) {
      String liked = "";
      StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(inputString);
      while (token.hasMoreElements()) {
         liked += token.nextToken(); 
         if (token.hasMoreElements()) {
            liked += " like ";
         }
      }
      return liked;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

**`String text = "That is so funny!";
 text = text.replaceAll("\\s\\b", " like ");`**

This will also make sure that all **" like " 's** come **in between** sentence. It will always put the "like" in between the text, not in the start or at the end. Even if the text is something like this `"This is so funny!     "` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

What about just replacing " " by " like " ?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm