# Trying to place a word in between the spaces of a string

Tags: java, string, char

I want to write a program that will insert the word "like" in between the spaces of each word in a sentence. 
What I have attempted so far:

```
public String teenTalk(String sentence)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
    {
       char sentC = sentence.charAt(i);
       String sentS = Character.toString(sentence);
       if (sentS.equals(" "))
       {
           sentence = sentence.replaceAll(" ", " like ");
       }
        return sentence;
    }
```

Please excuse any inefficiencies as I am still relatively new to programming in general. I recently got intensely into Strings and Chars, but I still lack much knowledge in how they work, so I'm guessing my code has illogical errors. I'd be thankful if someone could point them out.

I did find another forum on this ([Write method that puts the word "like" in between each of the words in the original sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080277/write-method-that-puts-the-word-like-in-between-each-of-the-words-in-the-origi)) asking for the same thing. However, the website that I have to turn this assignment into has an IDE that is extremely limited and will not compile tokens or lists. I have yet to test .replace and .replaceAll but I will place an update after I get my attempted code fixed. Thanks for any help inadvance

Comment: I'm not understanding the answers from the apparently duplicate question that I was linked to. Could I ask where I was going wrong? Did it have to due with the immutability of Strings?

Comment: Yes, `sentence.replaceAll` does not modify `sentence`. It returns a new String, so you need `sentence = sentence.replaceAll`.

Comment: My code still isn't working. I'm sorry to ask but are you able to see any error in my syntax?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, at least not in standard Java; there is no `Character.toString` method that takes a `String`. If I change the argument to `sentC` instead of `sentence` it produces an 'infinite' loop which tries to make the string infinitely long, although actually it dies when JVM heap is exhausted. `String.replaceAll` does what the name says, replace all occurrences, so you only need to call it once and only should call it once.